# String.Format phone number fill from left

Tags: c#, string, phone-number, string.format

I am using something like this:

```
String.Format("{0:+### ### ### ###}", System.Convert.ToInt64(str.Replace(" ", "")))
```

and it's ok when I have full number. But when I use it in TextBox and user is entering number then it's filling from right (+ 4, + 42, + 420, + 420 7,...) but I want to fill it from left (+4,+42,+420,+420 7, ...). How can I do this?

**Edit:** I find out thanks to comments that it's not good to convert phone number to integer but I am still looking for answer to my problem. Now withou using Convert.IoInt

Comment: Phone numbers should *not* be stored as integers. It's just a bad idea in terms of supporting leading zeroes etc.

Comment: Do you mean this: ##4 -> #42 happens to you and you want 4## -> 42#?

Comment: @JonSkeet you've right, I just didn't realize it but you have the point

Comment: @ofstream yea, that's what I mean